# Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR decrease DisconnectTimeout = 6 not working

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, .net-4.8

In .Net Framework, having an issue with Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.

Then I disable wifi on the client side, OnDisconnected event is fired after 40 seconds.
Expacted behavior is, it was fired after ~6 seconds.

Any suggestions?

In Global.asax, on Application_Start  following values are set:

```
 GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);

 GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
```